# In Six Ages, is exploring worth it?

Tags: six-ages-ride-like-the-wind

In **[Six Ages](https://store.steampowered.com/app/881420/Six_Ages_Ride_Like_the_Wind/)** (successor to **King of Dragon Pass** (yay)—released today, but I've tested the beta), whenever I **explored**, I would most of the time lose a few horses or gain a few goods. I would very rarely discover anything truly valuable or otherwise substantially beneficial. In addition, exploring costs an action and removes weaponthanes and a leader from the clan for a long period of time.

So is it generally considered to be **worth it**, to explore distant lands? Has it been made more worthwhile in the release version, perhaps? When I do find something interesting, it is as often good as bad, such as when I explore a mysterious forest but lose a leader. So it feels more like something interesting, flavour stuff, rather than something that one should strategically be doing to help the clan.

P.S. It may sound as though I were complaining, but I do like the game very much.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](https://sixages.fandom.com/wiki/Map#Exploration), there are some benefits for exploring

> Exploring lets you learn about new lands, filling in the map. But you
>   can explore anywhere - it's quite possible to find something new in a
>   place you've been to before. This even goes for your own clan lands.
>
> A side benefit of exploring is that it can make the valley safer. If
>   you don't explore, the threat of bandits or monsters can increase.
>
> Another benefit is that you can let other clans know what you've
>   discovered. This requires a dedicated venture, but will increasey your
>   standing, and the other clans may reveal knowledge of their own in
>   return.
>
> While exploring, you may also experience certain events.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Those are indeed benefits. I suppose I never noticed how bad banditry could be, because I always explore a lot. Even so, I wonder where exploring stands as to game balance, considering the cost..